# Remove a dark background from `geom_line` `ggplot2` legend

Tags: r, ggplot2, legend-properties

I am trying to build a plot with `geom_rect` and `geom_line`. I don't know how to remove dark color in the legend background after placing `geom_line`.

Here's my code

```
gp <- (gp 
       + ggplot2::geom_rect(data = dd5,
                              mapping = ggplot2::aes(xmin = begin, xmax = end+expPer,
                                                     ymin = order+0.35, ymax = order+0.25,
                                                     fill = description),
                              show.legend = T)
       
       + ggplot2::geom_line(data = dd6e, 
                            mapping = ggplot2::aes(x = begin,
                                                   y = order + 0.4*end,
                                                   group = order,
                                                   color = description),
                            show.legend = T)
       + guides(fill = guide_legend(override.aes = list(linetype = c(0))))
       + theme(axis.text.y=element_blank(),  #remove y axis labels
               axis.ticks.y=element_blank()) #remove y axis ticks
);
```

And here's the output, where the background is denoted in red.
[image]
Ideally, I'd also like to merge both descriptions into a single legend.
Cheers!
**[EDIT]** I tried:

- `scale_colour_manual` and it only modifies the colour of the first line
- `scale_fill_manual` and it modifies all rectangles except first one :/

Comment: `labs(fill="Description", color="Description")` may help you merge these legends

Comment: Where should I put it? I added it as the last element and it didn't work.